# Android image not auto-scaling or reflecting options settings

Tags: android, imageview

I'm new to android, and I haven't been able to find a workable solution within S.O.

I have a background for a game, I have resized images, with respect to the proper densities, and have them in my resource drawable density directories yet my image is still dorked up in the emulators.

I've also tried setting the BitmapFactory options but still no response:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Display display = ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
options.outHeight = size.x;
options.outWidth = size.y;

marioBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                               R.drawable.mario_bros_three,
                                               options );
```

Then drawing the bitmap with:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(marioBackground, 0, 0, null);
```

Yet I'm still seeing this in my mdpi emulator:

[image: Emulator Results]

Could someone point me in the right direction so that my image adheres to my set options or auto-scales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I was able to solve this issue but the solution ended up being something totally different than I expected.

Firstly, I had to remove the logic that was trying to stretch out the actual background image to match the window size using `BitmapFactory.Options`. So I remove the following:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Display display = ((Activity)context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
options.outHeight = size.x;
options.outWidth = size.y;

marioBackground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                                               R.drawable.mario_bros_three,
                                               options );
```

Secondly, I had to determine the scale factors for the width and height using the following (I placed this logic within my draw method):

```
final float scaleFactorX = (float) getWidth() / marioBackground.getWidth();
final float scaleFactorY = (float) getHeight() / marioBackground.getHeight();
```

Then within my draw method I had to scale the actual canvas using the canvas' scale method and the newly determined scale factors:

```
canvas.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
```

I did this prior to actual drawing the bitmap to the canvas:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(marioBackground, 0, 0, null);
```

So all together my draw method contains the following logic in order to properly scale my background image:

```
final float scaleFactorX = (float) getWidth() / marioBackground.getWidth();
final float scaleFactorY = (float) getHeight() / marioBackground.getHeight();

canvas.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);

canvas.drawBitmap(marioBackground, 0, 0, null);
```